# How does the canonical commutator works on differential operators?

Tags: commutative-algebra, quantum-mechanics, differential-operators

I'm having trouble understanding how the canonical commutator works on differential operators: in [this article](https://deliverypdf.ssrn.com/delivery.php?ID=152013104065027064082095065019017102101074051042007060126089029090123104127004075073055020029097121126020121083006097112011088059016075034036070003023100018120087080067045021074122026001076006071090070115024106126127121112070107094073106108083111125073&EXT=pdf&INDEX=TRUE), page 2, they define the multiplication-by-$x$ operator, that is a linear operator acting on some space of functions of the variable $x$, that simply multiplies any function by $x$. Then they extend it into the following time dependent operator:
$$\hat{x}(\tau)=e^{H\tau}xe^{-H\tau}$$
with $H=(a-bx)\partial_x+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial^2_x$.
Then they claim that in order to get the equation of motion (the derivative of $\hat{x}(\tau)$) they use the canonical commutator:
$$[\partial_x,x]=\partial_xx-x\partial_x=1$$
so that
$$[H,x]=a-bx+\sigma^2x\partial_x$$
and the equation of motion becomes
$$\frac{d}{d\tau}\hat{x}(\tau)=a-b\hat{x}(\tau)+\sigma^2\hat{x}(\tau)\hat{p}(\tau) \tag{1}$$
where $\hat{p}(\tau)=e^{H\tau}\partial_xe^{-H\tau}$.

I tryed to do the explicit calculation: $[H,x]=((a-bx)\partial_x+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial^2_x)x-x((a-bx)\partial_x+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial^2_x)=$ $(a-bx)\partial_xx-x(a-bx)\partial_x+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial^2_xx-x\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial^2_x=(a-bx)(\partial_xx-x\partial_x)+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial_x(\partial_xx-x\partial_x)=$ $a-bx+\frac{\sigma^2}{2}x\partial_x$ but I have a $\sigma^2/2$ here and not just $\sigma^2$ as they claim. Also I don't understand then how to get to the equation of motion since the right hand side seems to be just their $[H,x]$ multiplied by $e^{H\tau}$ on the left and $e^{-H\tau}$ on the right, but why should $e^{H\tau}[H,x]e^{-H\tau}$ equal $\frac{d}{d\tau}\hat{x}(\tau)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Notice that
   \begin{align}
   x\partial_x^2(x\psi)-x(x\partial_x^2\psi)&=x\partial_x(x\partial_x\psi+\psi)-x^2\partial_x^2\psi \\
   &=x(x\partial_x^2\psi+\partial_x\psi+\partial_x\psi)-x^2\partial_x^2\psi \\
   &=2x\partial_x\psi,
   \end{align}
   which explains the factor of $2$ that you are missing.
2. Differentiate $\hat{x}(\tau)=e^{H\tau}xe^{-H\tau}$ with respect to $\tau$ to obtain $\frac{d}{d\tau}\hat{x}(\tau)=e^{H\tau}[H,x]e^{-H\tau}.$